# How to implement time square calendar app

Tags: java, android, calendar, implementation

the link to the calendar app is https://github.com/square/android-times-square#usage

I'm trying to just simply implement this calendar app into my project, and I've been having the hardest time. I put the code into my main activity xml like it told me

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.chexity.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView
    android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and also put the code into my main activity's onCreate

```
package com.example.chexity;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

        CalendarPickerView calendar = (CalendarPickerView) findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);
        Date today = new Date();
        calendar.init(today, nextYear.getTime())
            .withSelectedDate(today);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

But I keep getting errors on this line

```
CalendarPickerView calendar = (CalendarPickerView) findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);
```

and also on the init method.

saying that calendarpickerview cannot be resolved to a type. I imported the library from the the calendar package I downloaded. I don't know what is wrong. Can anyone provide any insight?

I am running on version max 4.4 and min 2.2.

Comment: Hello - did you figure the solution to your problem?

Comment: I imported calendar picker view, but I keep getting this error.


`FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chexity/com.example.chexity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView
`

Comment: @Toheeb Were you able to find the solution for this. I am still stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't imported CalendarPickerView into your MainActivity.java file. Try this:

```
import com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView;
```

where your other import statements are.

Comment: I am not able to run it on my emulator, I keep getting this error, is there a fix?


`06-26 14:57:29.206: E/AndroidRuntime(423): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 14:57:29.206: E/AndroidRuntime(423): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chexity/com.example.chexity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView
`

Comment: I am having similar problem and so does importing import com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView; also shows similar error but this time it cannot see the com.squareup. I tried adding the library through Gradle and added TimeSquare project to my project.

Answer (score 0):

As i see you didn't set todays date for variable Date today;

You can replace

```
Date today = new Date();
```

with

```
Calendar c = getInstance();
Date today = c.getTime();
```